# Copyright with clipart images under Creative Commons

Tags: copyright, creative-commons

I want to make cards with pictures (to assist kids to visualise their activities) and offer these cards free of payment on my blog. 
I am not good at art and so I need to use images from the Internet. I have used clipart images that are licensed under Creative Commons. (Word gives you the option when inserting from the Internet). 
Is it legal for me to use these images in my product? 
I have tried to read up about this, but I just become confused.

Comment: *Which* creative commons license? CC BY? CC BY-SA? CC BY-ND? CC BY-NC? CC-0?

Comment: "I am not good at art and so I need to use images from the Internet." - This is false. You *could* opt to simply not to include any images at all. The feeling that you "must" violate copyright in order to do task XYZ does not mean that it is OK to do that.

Comment: @Brandin, you make me laugh. You're preaching to the choir. The best alternative when you can't draw, and can't figure out the copyright issues of the images on the internet, is to get a designer to draw pictures for you. Which is what I am in the process of doing. :-)

Comment: @Philipp, I don't even know. I would have to search for each image individually (and there are thirty or more of them) to find that. So I've decided to ask a designer to draw pictures for me.